# do any of the tts engines compatible with speech-dispatcher support sound icons?

Tags: text-to-speech

After digging around a bit I've found how to define the *SoundIconsFolder for a particular output module, but the only examples which define it say that the particular tts engine doesn't support sound-icons.

Has anyone used this functionality, and if so, which output module are you using?

-Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `festival-freebsoft-utils` package provides extensions to festival to support sound-icons and some other features as well.

I still need to read all of the docs to figure out how to configure it, but at least it seems promising.

If anyone else finds any other TTS engines which support sound-icons, I'd still like to hear about it.